# As of June 2017, which exchanges let you earn interest on your Bitcoin holdings by lending it out?

Tags: exchanges, lending, interest

I know poloniex can do lending to earn interest in your Bitcoin holders. Are there any other exchanges that let you learn interest in your Bitcoin holdings?

Comment: There are currently at least 45 cryptocurrency exchanges, possibly more than 100. I feel that the scope of this question is unreasonable, that a comprehensive answer can't be given, that it will be outdated in about two weeks, and that it will attract numerous partial and spam answers. This is pretty much a classic "shopping list question". Please ask for the solution of a specific problem to be solved instead of requesting someone to compile a menu for you.

Comment: Please 1. State the specific problem you're trying to solve. 2.
Describe what you've already tried, and why it hasn't worked. 3. 
Ask for help solving the problem by laying out what you need to happen for it to be successful. Also see, this [full treatise of "Shopping List Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185486/232061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitfinex allows you to lend BTC, USD and others.  Current rates for BTC are about 4% APR.
[Bitfinex](http://www.bitfinex.com)